# custom sorting or ordering a table without resorting the whole shebang

Tags: sql, sorting, replication

For ten years we've been using the same custom sorting on our tables, I'm wondering if there is another solution which involves fewer updates, especially since today we'd like to have a replication/publication date and wouldn't like to have our replication replicate unnecessary entries.I had a look into nested sets, but it doesn't seem to do the job for us.

Base table:

```
id | a_sort
---+-------
1    10
2    20
3    30
```

After inserting:

```
insert into table (a_sort) values(15)
```

An entry at the second position.

```
id | a_sort
---+-------
1    10
2    20
3    30
4    15
```

Ordering the table with:

```
select * from table order by a_sort
```

**and resorting all the a_sort entries**, updating at least id=(2,3,4)
will of course produce the desired output:

```
id | a_sort
---+-------
1    10
4    20
2    30
3    40
```

The column names, the column count, datatypes, a possible join, possible triggers or the way the resorting is done is/are irrelevant to the problem.Also we've found some pretty neat ways to do this task fast.

only; how the heck can we reduce the updates in the db to 1 or 2 max.

Seems like an awfully common problem.

The captain obvious in me thougth once "use an a_sort float(53), insert using a fixed value of ordervaluefirstentry+abs(ordervaluefirstentry-ordervaluenextentry)/2".
But this would only allow around 1040 "in between" entries - so never resorting seems a bit problematic ;)

Comment: Ooh, that makes for a cracking new tag, that does

Comment: a very infrequently used new tag?

Comment: Sorry, don't get the problem. How is the Select updating anything? You see a result set ordered by a_sort, the ids are in arbitrary order, why do you care? Adding semantics to ids is often not a good idea.

Comment: To add to djna's comment - how are duplicate a_sort values handled?  If there won't be, the pk should be the a_sort column.

Comment: @djna: actually, i did'nt want to spend more time on explaining how the resorting actually is done but if it is helpful to understand the problem i will edit it in tomorrow morning (~10:00gmt+1). still, the question would'nt be how to resort but how to "insert an entry into a table with a fixed order value in between two other existing values so later on it can be sorted/ordered by using the sql order by clause" - if that would be possible. any ideas on how not to do it the same way as i do are most welcomed.

Comment: @rexem: without resorting there would be duplicate a_sort entries. the offset of 10 is only used to make the first insert somewhere in between. would also work with even and odd numbers. it does'nt work well with replication.

Comment: @djna: about the arbitary order: the idea would be to insert it at the second position - in the final "select * from table order by a_sort" - sorry i can't describe this another way. my bad.

Comment: If an a_sort value of 20 exists, and you are inserting a value of 20 - which gets keeps its a_sort value?  The existing or the new one?  And what database are you dealing with - SQL Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't describe what you're doing with this data, so forgive me if this is a crazy idea for your situation:

You could make a sort of 'linked list' where instead of a column of values, you have a column for the 'next highest valued' id. This would decrease the number of updates to a maximum of 2.

You can make it doubly linked and also have a column for next lowest, which would bring the maximum number of updates to 3.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: with a linked list with ids (common in oop) i'd have a problem with the recursive select statement to get to the ordered data. how would you write the sql(-92) statement?

Comment: You could easily sort it on the client side. Select ordering by the link column so you get the null first (assuming doubly linked, otherwise you need a head node) then loop through until you get another null. I assume you are sorting on the client side for the update anyway. You could do it using a stored procedure too.